# Mysql: join to include all rows (even where SUM=0)

Tags: mysql

I have DB with two tables: 
**rmonth** and **alternatives**

The rmonth is an aggregated table of data for each alternative a complete month - if they have any - otherwise the row don't exist in the rmonth table.

Now I want to join them, and this is my code:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(rmAntal, 0) AS sumMonth, aID, aText, rmUnitID 
FROM
alternatives
  LEFT JOIN
rmonth ON aID = rmAltID
WHERE aToQuestID = 4418
AND rmMonth = 3
AND rmYear = 2018
AND rmUnitID IN (10603,10960,10496)
GROUP BY aID, rmUnitID
ORDER BY aID ASC
```

But it doesn't give me the rows not existing in rmonth.
So this scenario gives me the result as I want it - except that it can't handle where the alternative does not exist for that specific unitID in rmonth. 
I want them listed with just 0 in sumMonth.

Unfortunately that's where my MySQL-knowledge is limited.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `OR` operator, for example

```
...
WHERE aToQuestID = 4418 AND rmMonth IS NULL OR (
   AND rmMonth = 3
   AND rmYear = 2018
   AND rmUnitID IN (10603,10960,10496)
)
...
```

This way, you'll get all your `alternatives` data, even when it's counter part in `rmonth` is null.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply. It doesn't give an error, but I exited the query after five minutes without any result. The query without your addition runs in 0.062 sec (but excludes a few rows).
If I move the parentheses to (rmMonth is Null OR rmMonth = 3) gives same output as my initial query..

Comment: if that's the case then you must have many records and some poor indexing. have you tried to place an `EXPLAIN` before the select statement to view where your bottle neck is?